# Can't log in desktop environment after moving `/` and `/home` into different LVs and enlarge swap

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, lvm, swap

I enlarged  LV `swap` from 1G to 4G. I also  moved `/` and `/home` in a single PV to two different LVs, by shrinking  LV `root` and create  LV `home` on the freed space,  and then following https://askubuntu.com/a/923943/1471

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/home
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-home  /mnt/home/
$ sudo cp -r /home/* /mnt/home/
$ sudo mv /home /home-orig
$ sudo mkdir /home
```

and modified `/etc/fstab` into the following content, where I renamed `/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1` to `/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap` (because I have renamed LV from default name `swap_1` to `swap` by `lvrename`), and add a line for mounting `/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-home` at `/home`.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0C1E-EE69  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
# my change:
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-home /home               ext4    defaults 0       2
```

After I reboot, it seems that LV `home` is correctly mounted at `/home`:

```
$ pwd
/home/t
t@olive:~$ df .
Filesystem                   1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-home 425480640 180336 403617312   1% /home
```

but there are two problems

1. although I can still login in virtual console, I can't log in LXDE of Lubuntu.
2. `free` shows that the swap size is still 1GB.

   ```
   $ free -h
                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:           3.3G        196M        2.9G        5.3M        239M        2.9G
   Swap:          979M          0B        979M
   $ cat /proc/swaps 
   Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
   /dev/dm-1                               partition   1003516 0   -2
   $ ls /dev/mapper/ -la
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     120 Feb 23 16:47 .
   drwxr-xr-x 22 root root    4260 Feb 23 16:47 ..
   crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Feb 23 16:47 control
   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 23 16:52 lubuntu--vg-home -> ../dm-2
   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 23 16:52 lubuntu--vg-root -> ../dm-0
   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Feb 23 16:52 lubuntu--vg-swap -> ../dm-1
   ```

How can I solve the problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters your `cp` hasn't retained permissions or ownerships. Use `cp -a` instead of `cp -r`.

To be going on, you haven't resized swap itself, just the LV where swap is stored. You'll need to rerun `mkswap`.

Comment: Thanks. `cp -a` works. Strange. before that, why could I log into virtual console but not desktop environment?

Comment: The GUI environment probably needs to write/create files in your home directory. A console login definitely doesn't.

Comment: What files are written to or create if I may ask?

Comment: A console login usually runs a shell, which usually needs to write command history to your $HOME.

Comment: 炸鱼薯条德里克 a console login doesn't _need_ to write command history. The session won't fail if the write fails.

Comment: @Tim I don't know, but you can find out easily enough by running something like `find . -mmin 5` just after logging in.