# Why do we need both mkswap and /etc/fstab to set up swap?

Tags: linux, fstab, swap

Given

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
...
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

why do we still need:

```
$ sudo swapoff /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap
$ sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap
$ sudo swapon /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap
```

?

In other wors, why do we need both `mkswap` and `/etc/fstab` to set up swap? What do  `mkswap` and `/etc/fstab` do differently?

My question comes from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502591/674

Thanks.

Comment: mkswap sets up the swap space. fstab just saws to use the swap space (eliminating the need to manually use swapon on boot).

Answer (score 1):

As already said by jordanm, fstab is just a file containing the information of your filesystems to be mounted and the swap devices to be enabled on boot. You don't wan't to do that manually.

Have a look at the man pages of `mount` and `swapon`:

mount (8)

```
 -a, --all
              Mount all filesystems (of the given types) mentioned in fstab (except for those whose line contains the
              noauto keyword). The filesystems are mounted following their order in fstab.
```

swapon (8)

```
 -a, --all
              All devices marked as ``swap'' in /etc/fstab are made available, except for those with the ``noauto''
              option. Devices that are already being used as swap are silently skipped.
```

The command `mkswap` creates the swap device, just as `mkfs.ext4` creates an ext4 filesystem on a device.

Answer (score 0):

If you want swap to used post reboot also

Then entry of the swap partition details should be in /etc/fstab